# Construct a bounded set of reals with exactly three limit points

Tags: metric-spaces

I tried doing that, but I didn't get anything at all.

Could you provide me with some hints?

What I'm sure of Is that, such a set doesn't contain any interval and it's infinite so I think it's a set like cantor's one or something like that.

Comment: You’re trying to make it too complicated. Start by finding a set with exactly one limit point; Seth’s hint would be a good place to begin.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Consider the set $\{ 1/n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.  Can you use this set to solve the problem?

Comment: I think that is a good hint!

Comment: If we let, $H=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{1+\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{2+\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, then $H$ has exactly three limit points, which are $0,1$ and $2$, right?

Comment: @MathsLover yup, you got it.

Comment: @MathsLover Note that, as you said, the set does not contain any interval, and yet it is much simpler than a Cantor set.